# Show that the distance between these two sets is not bounded.

Tags: metric-spaces, metric-geometry, geodesic

I have a homework question that asks:

"Consider the curve $\gamma : [1, \infty] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\gamma (t) = \langle t \cos (\ln t), t \sin (\ln t) \rangle$.  Show that this curve is not a bounded distance from a geodesic."

It looks a little cryptic, so here is how I decoded the statement.  Say I have two points $p_1 = \gamma (t_1)$ and $p_2 = \gamma (t_2)$ on the curve (say $t_1 < t_2$).  I get the straight line (a.k.a. the geodesic) between them to be
$$ D = \{ (1-t) p_1 + t p_2 : t \in [0, 1] \}. $$
On the other hand, if I follow the curve $\gamma$, I get the set
$$ G = \{ \gamma (t) : t \in [t_1, t_2] \}. $$
Now the question amounts to showing
$$ \sup_{d \in D, g \in G} \{ dist(d, g) \} $$
is not bounded. I *think* this is the way to go about the question, but I don't know where to go from here.

EDIT:
The supremum will of course be bounded for fixed $p_1$ and $p_2$, but I want it to depend on the choice of points $p_1$ and $p_2$ somehow.  In other words, the curve $\gamma$ gets arbitrarily far away from straight lines connecting points of $\gamma$.

Comment: Whatever the question means, the curve $\gamma$ is a logarithmic spiral beginning at $(1,0)$ and going off to infinity turning in the counterclockwise direction.

Comment: Are you sure you want to take the distance from something in $G$ (i.e. a point on the path from $t_1$ to $t_2$) to a geodesic to be $\sup_{d \in D}{\mathrm{dist}(d,g)}$? This means the *largest* distance we can find from the geodesic to the point.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Consider a line $\{p+ tv\}$ so that if $w\cdot v=0,\ |w|=1$,
then
$$ (p+tv)\cdot w =p\cdot w $$ for all pt in a line

This line determines two half planes $$ \{ q| w\cdot q \leq\ (or\
\geq )\ p\cdot w \} $$

(2) Assume that the curve $\gamma$ is bounded distance from some
geodesic Then it is in some half plane $$ (\gamma (t)-p)\cdot w \leq
0 $$ for some $p$ and some $w=(w_1,w_2)$

In other words $$w_1t\cos\ \ln\ t+w_2t\sin\ \ln\ t \leq C$$ for some
$C$ By considering $t$ where $ln\ t=2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2} $ or
$2n\pi + \frac{3\pi}{2}$ we have the term $w_2t\sin\ \ln\ t$ which
is large Hence we have a contradiction.